# Hovering not working when in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I put a Div box in a table cell that should slide up once its hovered over. When I hover over it, it doesn't do anything. I have tried the code below without success.

I also tried the Javascript way which didn't work either.

```
<td>
Product 1
<div id="p1" class="bottombox"></div></td>

.bodytable td #p1{
    bottom:-10px;
}
.bodytable td #p1:hover{
    bottom:-130px;
    width: 50%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hovering is actually working. Try to give `background` color to the `div` and you will see it.

Also if you haven't specified div position as `absolute` than `bottom` property will not work like this. Perhaps you wanted to have `margin-bottom` or `padding-bottom`?

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/T5BQn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

you can´t see what happens on hover because your p1 class is empty.

Try:

```
<div id="p1" class="bottombox">Product 1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? It uses the `height` property. http://jsfiddle.net/vBdne/

If you want the hidden to stick, you're gonna want to use javascript.